# Configuring postfix and opendkim socket value

Tags: postfix, opendkim

I have the following line in my /etc/postfix/main.cf
`smtpd_milters=inet:127.0.0.1:8891 inet:127.0.0.1:8893`
So then What should I put for Socket in /etc/default/opendkim or /etc/opendkim.conf ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want OpenDKIM to open a listening socket on port 8891, put the following in /etc/opendkim.conf.

```
Socket inet:8891@127.0.0.1
```

Postfix will then try to reach this milter using the `smtpd_milters` setting shown in your question.

Follow one of many, many online guides available for how to set up OpenDKIM. For example the [quickstart in Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/opendkim).

Comment: Why are there 2, 8891 and 8893? I'm supposed to define sockets for both in opendkim.conf ?

Comment: Well don't put two ports then. Configure one in /etc/opendkim.conf and the same one in /etc/postfix/main.cf.

Comment: Usually `opendmarc` uses `8893`. Did you install that, too?